# Why is my angular paging not working?

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs, angularjs-scope

The paging worked when data was populated on load.  After I included enteredValue/search functionality to populate ng-grid I no longer see 5 items per page and the next/previous buttons don't work.  I believe the change of data in gridOptions from 'myData' to 'source' broke the pagination.  I am trying to pass $scope.source into  setPagingData function but having issues.  How do I get the paging to work properly?

```
 $scope.setPagingData = function(data, page, pageSize) {
            var pagedData = data.slice((page - 1) * pageSize, page * pageSize);
            $scope.myData = pagedData;

            $scope.totalServerItems = data.length;
            if (!$scope.$$phase) {
              $scope.$apply();
            }
          };

 $scope.gridOptions = {
            data: 'source',
            enablePaging: true,
            pagingOptions: $scope.pagingOptions,
            showFooter: true
          };
```

Here's [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/uf45TcUCkzEs7oMjPROO?p=preview)

Comment: Well without proper code in plunker it would be hard to tackle this issue. However existing version has mixed up parameters. `getPagedDataAsync` receives array of objects into parameter `url` and it's expected that `$http.get(url)` fails... Also is there a reason to use so outdated angular version? I found it easier to debug in 1.2.1

Comment: Ok.  I'll update my angular version, give gridOptions filtered data, and let you know if it works.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, let's assume we add such a piece of code to use mock data in controller.

```
          $scope.getPagedDataAsync = function(url, pageSize, page, searchText) {
            setTimeout(function() {
                var data;
                 /// this is new and required only for sake of plunker
                if(typeof url !== 'string'){
                  $scope.setPagingData(url, page, pageSize);
                }
```

Now it becomes clear that you messed up grid options and provided as source unfiltered data.

```
          $scope.gridOptions = {
            data: 'source',//should be myData
            enablePaging: true,
            pagingOptions: $scope.pagingOptions,
            showFooter: true
          };
```